# How can I use opencv-3.0.0 with java project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv3.0

I used opencv-2.4.8 before it contains .jar file what you need is only to add this jar file to your java project [as in this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html) ... but when I install this version it does not contain the build file that contain these jar files.

[image]

Comment: Are you using maven or any other dependency manager?

Comment: No ... I do not use maven.

Comment: I used opencv-2.4.8 before it contains .jar file what you need is only to add this jar file to your project ... but when I install this version it does not contain the build file that contain these jar files.